# Using php cURL to set a cookie on a subdomain

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use curl to set a cookie on a subdomain. Everything is working except for the cookie being set.

Am I wrong to think the following sets a cookie across all subdomains?

```
setcookie('cookiename','value', time()+3600,"/",".domain.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

> Am I wrong to think the following sets a cookie across all subdomains?

Yes, you are wrong. [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) is not related to curl in any way. So this won't work.

You might be looking for `CURLOPT_COOKIE` and similar curl options, see [*Sending cookie in cURL request*](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?572402-Sending-cookie-in-cURL-request).

Further on, you find the actual specification [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) more specifically [5.2.3. The Domain Attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.3).

Comment: I know its not related. What I am doing is sending info from domain.com to subdomain.domain.com via curl, logging in which sets the cookie I need, then returning with true or false. It isn't setting the cookie, that's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I still don't get what you ask for.

Comment: I am trying to set a cookie on a subdomain from my main domain via cURL

Comment: Set the cookie for what? Request or Response? cURL or some users Browser?

Comment: there is a difference between curl and php in general, curl is a library to handle url requests by yourself in php – normally you don't "speak" to your users using curl, maybe you can explain a little more in detail what you are trying to accomplish and what you are doing exactly at the moment?